# CLLocationManager.desiredAccuracy with kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation will sometimes snap to roads

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I added a GPS tracker to my iOS app (POI Toolbox). Now the `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` setting seems to make the `CLLocationManager` assume I am moving on a road when there is one nearby. However, this does not always happen and I just noticed it now.

On the screenshots you can see very clearly what I mean (the marker is on the place where the Location Manager used my real position again, whilst I have been on the bike path besides the road - the red line).

This problem is very annoying, because the new version of my app is already in the AppStore. This causes such trackings, like on the screenshots.

Does anyone know the problem or has deeper insights into the Location Manager? How did you solve it? Can anyone say for sure that the `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` setting will avoid this problem?

[image: Tracking]

Answer (score 0):

Well, how embarrassing this is... I found in my code:

```
locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation
```

And will try to replace it by:

```
locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeFitness
```

I hope this will solve it.

Comment: Sometimes, it still happens again. My next test will be using ```kCLLocationAccuracyBest``` instead of ```kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation```. I think ```kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation``` lets the location manager look up map data and snap to roads.

Comment: Apple seems to recommend using `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` for fitness related tasks, at least they use it in their examples: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/creating_a_workout_route

Comment: Well, it didn't do the job. The solution seems to be to set the device to flight mode. This will stop position fixing.